# If $Y$ is a metric subspace of $X$. A subset $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$ if and only if $E=Y ∩ G$ for some open subset G of X.

Tags: metric-spaces

If we take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $Y=Z$ and $E=\mathbb{N}$ i.e. $\{1,2,3,4,5,\cdots\}$ then since for this case $E$ is open in $Y$ (as $Y$ is itself an entire metric space) however there does not exist any open set $G$ in $X$ for this particular set. then how $E$ is open in $Y$.

Pl clarify

Comment: Why do you insist on extra notation? Just use $\mathbb{R,Z,N}$ instead of $X,Y,E$. Also what is "Pl clarify"?

Comment: Also, why does $Y$ being an "entire metric space" imply that it is open in $E$? Any subset of a metric space is a metric space. $Y$ is open in $E$ in this case, but still...

Comment: These X, Y, and E are the letters from baby Rudin, though he does not specifically call them the reals, naturals, etc. This is think is a problem created to understand the theorem 2.30.   Pl clarify:= Please Clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Take $G = (0,\infty)$. $                 $

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be fancy, let $$U=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(n-\frac12,n+\frac12\right)\;;$$ then $U$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$, and $U\cap\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z^+$. But there’s no need to go to so much trouble, as Sean’s answer shows. For that matter, you could observe that $\Bbb Z_{\le0}=\Bbb Z\setminus\Bbb Z^+$ is a closed set in $\Bbb R$, so $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z_{\le0}$ is an open set in $\Bbb R$ whose intersection with $\Bbb Z$ is clearly $\Bbb Z^+$.